# How to delete a python variable whose name is only known at runtime?

Tags: python

I need to do the equivalent of the `del` statement when the variable name is only known dynamically.

For the global namespace, I believe `del globals()[name]` works correctly.

For the local namespace, `del locals()[name]` is incorrect since `locals()` is not guaranteed to be the original dictionary (and, in fact, in CPython it is a copy).
For the same reason, `exec(f'del {name}')` also won't work.

Comment: is it not working by using del in the same scope?

Comment: ```def delete_local_variable(name):
    locals_dict = locals()
    if name in locals_dict:
        delattr(locals_dict['__builtins__'], name)```

Comment: ohh then i will remove it, it would be better if you could share code through which i can reproduce the scenerio

Comment: Dynamically named locals? How did you end up with this problem? How did you *create* dynamically named locals in the first place? Taking this question at face value, I’m pretty sure the answer is “you can’t”, but there is also almost certainly an XY problem here.

Comment: @Ry- Trying to create a context manager that emulates a scope to reduce bugs in Jupyter notebooks cells, near loops, etc. The context manager would delete all variables that were created between its `__enter__` and `__exit__`. Except that it seems it is impossible.

Comment: This is an x-y problem. This should simply not be done. There should be no "unknown" variables.

Comment: @zvone May I ask why my attempt to create `scope` context manager was a bad idea? I wanted to write `with scope(): ...` around loops (among other things) to keep namespace cleaner in my Jupyter notebooks. This is similar to what you can do in Go and JS using := / let syntax, and similar to what you get in C++/Java/C# automatically.

Comment: In c++, every block of code has its scope. In Python, only functions have their local scopes. If you what to have a local score, create a function. Also, is you are developing something too big to be handled nicely in a Jupyter notebook, don't do it in a notebook - implement some proper python modules and run them the way grown up applications are meant to be run.

Comment: @zvone Breaking up code into smaller functions is best practice in every language, not just python. Yet most major languages found it useful to allow creating variables scoped to a loop (and many languages went beyond that and made it the only way one could define variables). I understand everyone has their own preferred style of coding, but "should simply not be done" seems to be an unnecessarily strong statement. Anyway, I found a similar discussion where people were sketching something similar: https://discuss.python.org/t/should-loops-be-in-their-own-scope-poll/10593/14

Answer (score 0):

I now believe this is not possible. The only API python exposes to unbind a name from the local namespace is the `del` statement.